# Does Startup Application manager in Ubuntu 14.04 not exist?

Tags: 14.04

Most of the guides state to search for startup app but nothing comes up in my end. Any suggestions?

More information of what I already did:

1. Tried searching startup app in the Dash. Only startup disk creator comes up.
2. Tried running gnome-session-properties in Terminal. tells me:

   The program 'gnome-session-properties' is currently not installed. You can install it 
   by typing:
   sudo apt-get install gnome-session-bin
3. If I try to install gnome-session-bin I am told it is already installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search in the Dash for *Startup Applications* and click the Startup Applications icon to open a **Startup Applications Preferences** window. From the Startup Applications Preferences window you can add, remove or edit additional startup programs.

You can also open the Startup Applications Preferences window from the terminal using the command `gnome-session-properties`

If you have installed the *gnome-session-bin* package in Ubuntu 14.04 then the gnome-session-properties executable file should be found at `/usr/bin/gnome-session-properties` and it can be run by double-clicking the gnome-session-properties icon. If the gnome-session-properties icon is not there in the `/usr/bin/` directory, then you can go to the [Package: gnome-session-bin](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gnome-session-bin) webpage, scroll down on the webpage to the **Download gnome-session-bin** heading, and then download the gnome-session-bin package, either amd64 or i386 depending on your OS's architecture. The gnome-session-properties file is there in the archive you downloaded in the `/usr/bin` folder. You can extract the gnome-session-properties file and copy it (using sudo cp path/to/the/gnome-session-properties/file /usr/bin/) to the `/usr/bin/` directory from the terminal.

Comment: That is what I tried but only startup disk creator comes uo.

Comment: I tried running gnome-session-properties and got the error that it wasnt installed and I should install gnome-session-bin. apt-get only informed me that this was already installed.

Comment: thanks that last step worked. Any idea why I would not show up? when manually installing gnome-session-bin from your link it states that I am downgrading from 3.12.1 to 3.9.90.

Comment: There is a bug report about this issue: [The program 'gnome-session-properties' is currently not installed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1310003) occurring with a version of gnome-session-bin greater than 3.9.90 [origin: LP-PPA-gnome3-team-gnome3-staging]. My Ubuntu 14.04 which was updated today has gnome-session-bin Version: 3.9.90-0ubuntu12 and when I checked in Synaptic it said that there were no other available versions of gnome-session-bin.

Comment: I check gnome3-staging's `gnome-session-bin` today, they missed the `gnome-session-properties` file in deb package